# Share Intent doesnt work for image?

Tags: android, android-intent, share

```
private void createShareIntent() {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    String file = "/mnt/sdcard/9gag_4155804.jpg";
    File f = new File(file);
    if (!f.exists()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File doesnt exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "We can go on!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "How do you want to share?"));
}
```

The file exists and I don't receive the Toast. 
When calling this method many intents are listet. (Google Drive, Mail, Plus etc)
I click on Google Plus and it tells me "not all media files could be append to the post".
Same happens when using Google Drive or any other service.
I just cannot share any image...

Any ideas?

// edit
I get the Toast "We can go on!!!"

Comment: try to put Toast in `else` and check...

Comment: added and i get the toast that "we can go on"

Comment: Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` and check you have image in folder you gave path

Comment: Yeah the image is there. It's accessible by other applications too...

Comment: try mnt/sdcard/9gag_4155804.jpg instead of /mnt/sdcard/9gag_4155804.jpg

Answer (score -3):

Have you defined an intent filter in your manifest.? If not add this:

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType-"image/*"/>
 </intent-filter>
```

You need to notify to the android system that this is an implicit intent.

Comment: The Intent Filter is used to tell the Android system that my app can receive shared images, or?

Comment: yes, you need to declare this in your manifest so that the android system lists your app in the list.. when u click on share button

Comment: I dont want to receive sharings. I want to share some images to other applications